# Modify all objects in a linked list - java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am having trouble with a linked list I'm working on.  I've created my own linked list of Employee objects.  Each Employee object contains all your normal data like name, address, contact info, salary, years of employment etc.

What I am trying to do create a method in my list class which would modify all the objects in the list.  For instance, I could increment the "years of employment" by 1 or I could increase the "salary" of all Employees in the list by 5% to give everyone a raise.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of the ListNode class?

Comment: I added the ListNode Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would have a get method for the ListNode class in the form of listNode.getEmployee() and then you can just treat that object as an Employee object. So for example:

```
ListNode temp = first;
while (temp != null){
    temp.getEmployee().incrementYears(1);
    temp = temp.getNext();
}
```

But its hard to tell if we don'the ListNode and Employee classes implementations.

Answer (score 1):

so you have to call the change method on each object inside the List

```
LinkedList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public void increaseYearOfEmployment() {
    for (Employee e : employees) 
            e.yrsEmployed++;   //  instance variable
}

public void increaseSalary() {
    for (Employee e : employees) 
            e.yrsSalary++;       //  instance variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Employee fields were not set to private:

```
LinkedList<Employee> employees; //employee instance variable

...

public void increaseYrsEmployment() {
    for (Employee e : employees) e.yrsEmployed++;
}
```

If the Employee fields are set to private, you can add getter and setter methods to the class Employee to enable the fields to be accessed and modified.

Comment: Well I want to create the list and run the method in my main while keeping the definition in my list class.  I updated original post to show this.